# How do I solve $\sqrt{y^2+1}\,dx = xy\,dy$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following:

$$\sqrt{y^2+1}\,dx = xy\,dy$$

I have never met equations with roots yet. the only thing I exactly know that this equation is with separable variables, what is the generic way to handle roots in equations? (If any)

Comment: Separate variables, $$ \frac{dx}{x} = \frac{y \, dy}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}, $$ and then both sides are derivatives of simple functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a separable equation.

Consider $\sqrt{y^2+1}dx=xydy$
And then move all functions of y to one side and all functions of x to the other side.

$\frac{ydy}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}=\frac{dx}{x}$

and then you proceed to integrate both sides. Can you take it from there?

Comment: yep, I got $$\sqrt{y^2+1}=\ln |x|$$, but the answer also includes $$x=0$$, I have no idea why :(

Comment: @M.Mass I suppose that $$y$$ is a function of $$x,   \, y=f(x) \ $$ in this case your solution can't be x=something...

Comment: @M.Mass if you already know the solution, stop worrying about it and go through the separation of variables. Indeed, the solution is not going to be defined at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

After separating the equation assume

$y^2 + 1 = z $; 
taking differential
$2y dy =dz$
now the equation becomes
$\frac{dz}{2\sqrt{z}}=\frac{dx}{x}$